# Convert .load to .ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm struggling to convert the following from using .load to .ajax which I need to do as I'd like to use ajaxComplete to initiate a plugin after an ajax call has been made.

below is the current code I have, and I need some guidence on how to convert it as I've reached a brick wall.

```
$('.pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum).load(nextLink + ' .post',
            function() {



                // Update page number and nextLink.
                                    $( this ).hide().fadeIn(500);
                pageNum++;
                                    nextLink = nextLink.replace(/paged[=].[0-9]*/, 'paged='+ pageNum);

                // Add a new placeholder, for when user clicks again.
                $('#pbd-alp-load-posts')
                    .before('<div class="pbd-alp-placeholder-'+ pageNum +'"></div>')
                $.ajax({});
                // Update the button message.
                if(pageNum <= max) {
                    $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('Load More Posts');
                                            $('#contentWrapper').stellar('refresh');
                } else {
                    $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').text('No more posts to load.');
                }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(element).load( url [, data ] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ] )
```

can be converted in to this

```
$.ajax(function(){
            url:"",
            data:{},
            complete:function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
           }
});
```

with this you can convert it little by little =)

Example:

```
$("#myelemdiv").load("/not-here.php",{"mydata":"hellodata"} function(response, status, xhr) {

});
```

can be converted into like this

```
$.ajax(function(){
            url:"/not-here.php",
            data:{"mydata":"hellodata"},
            complete:function(response, status, xhr){
              $("#myelemdiv").html(response);
           }
});
```

Comment: The main point in using load for most people is to provide an identifier within the html at which to filter the results against. To emulate this, we would do `success:function(data){ $(data).find(selector)`. Which would be the same as `.load(url + selector`

Comment: It is not an equivalence. load is synchronous and execute the target JS scripts (except fragment loading method).